# how to make onKeyPress download link use html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeypress

Merhaba, bir tuşa basıldığında indirme başlayacak ve atanmış farklı tuşlarda farklı linklere gidecek şekilde yapılabilir mi onu soracaktım? örnekte verdiğiniz download linki gibi ama linke tıklayarak değil tuşa basıp direkt indirme başlayacak şekilde yapmak istiyorum. Ben yapamadım da yardımcı olur musunuz lütfen.

Hi, when I press a key, I will ask for it to start downloading and go to different links with different assigned keys? I like to download the link you gave in the example but not by clicking on the link, I would like to start downloading directly by pressing the key. Please help me if I can not do it.

related link: http://www.prototurk.com/video/jquery-ile-klavyede-basilan-tusa-gore-islem-yapmak/377

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to simulate the click of a link when you press a key. For that you can use the function `trigger('click')` of Jquery.
If you not use Jquery, you can find in this website how to do it in Vanilla JS http://2ality.com/2013/06/triggering-events.html